# Closure of finite rank operators on $L^p$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, compactness

It well-known that,  an operator $T:H\to H$ on a Hilbert space, is compact if and only if T is limit of finite rank operators.

Besides this, the results by [Per Enflo 1973](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-130/issue-none/A-counterexample-to-the-approximation-problem-in-Banach-spaces/10.1007/BF02392270.full) shows that this results is not true in general on Banach spaces.

My question is to know whether, this results is true at least on $L^p$-spaces? That is

**An operator a compact $T:L^p\to L^p$  is limit of finite rank operators?**

I am looking for references or any results in this direction.

Comment: Yes, because these spaces have a basis. (For the case $L_\infty$ you can use a different argument). The approximation property is the term to look up.

Comment: You mean every Banach space with a Basis has this property? Especially separable spaces?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923634/show-that-every-compact-operator-on-banach-space-is-a-norm-limit-of-finite-rank